# Is there a shortcut to site:youtube.com (search for videos on Youtube directly from a search bar)?

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

I use different search engines and anytime I need to search specifically on google all I need to do is type !g

Is there a shortcut for Youtube as well because typing site:youtube.com takes too much time - Ideally I would need something like !y (this unfortunately searches in yahoo.com)

Answer (score 1):

On A Chrome address bar try to type `y`.
If `youtube.com` appears just press tab to search on youtube.

Comment: does this still work?